# Display a digital clock with different starting time than 00:00:00:00 c#

Tags: c#, time, counter

I searched but I seem to be missing something.
I am trying to display a digital clock that will begin counting when you hit the start button. That one is easy. What I can't figure out is that if I want to start the clock from let's say 00:00:05:00 , the moment the clock reaches its first second it displays 00:00:51:00 rather than 00:00:06:00.
The code I use is

```
TimeSpan ts2 = sw2.Elapsed;
currentTime2 = String.Format("{0:}"+hour.ToString("D1")+":{1:}"+min.ToString("D1")
                                         +":{2:}"+sec.ToString("D1")+":{3:}"+ms.ToString("D1"),
                ts2.Hours, ts2.Minutes, ts2.Seconds, ts2.Milliseconds / 10);
txtClock2.Text = currentTime2;
```

where hour , min , sec , ms are ints given the value of 0 in the first case and 0 except the int sec that is given the value of 5 in the second case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A much cleaner solution would be to use `ToString` on the `TimeSpan` instance and use a format string to get the desired output.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) is a link showing some examples of various formats to create the desired formatting.

Comment: Any particular reason for a down vote based on the information given considering proper implementation would solve the issue?

Comment: What you said was down right to the point. Thanks a lot. I do not know why it shows a minus 1 vote. All I did was check the acceptance button

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan ts1 = sw1.Elapsed;
            txtClock1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss\\:ff}", ts1 + tsDiff);
```

where tsDiff is the ammount of time I want the clock to start from, expressed as a TimeSpan

That is the best way to do it